# Benefits of symfony2 security over storing in session variable on own?

Tags: symfony

How does Symfony's security component work?

Currently, I grab user login data, auth them against a database, and store their info in a session variable to log them in. When a user accesses a page, it checks their session to ensure they have rights to view a specific page. All of this is organized into services.

I've been looking into Symfony's security component but can't figure out exactly how it works. Specifically, is there some extra security benefit (I have an admin panel that I need to have proper security on) that it offers?

I also hate learning framework specific stuff without understanding what's going on, so would appreciate a general breakdown of how the component works.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This video is a good resource of how the security component works. The video is from the Symfony live conference in Paris last year. The speaker Johannes Schmitt is the one who has led the development of the security component.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lSxgEK8WKGA

Comment: I wrote my own security component earlier to avoid relying on the Symfony security framework, but I definitely neet to use a better one, so I'll check it out for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Security is a two-step process whose goal is to prevent a user from accessing a resource that he/she should not have access to.

In the first step of the process, the security system identifies who the user is by requiring the user to submit some sort of identification. This is called authentication, and it means that the system is trying to find out who you are.

Once the system knows who you are, the next step is to determine if you should have access to a given resource. This part of the process is called authorization, and it means that the system is checking to see if you have privileges to perform a certain action.

More information can be found at :
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html

Comment: Yeah I've already read the documentation, and even checked out the source code. I'm looking for a deeper description, specifically how it works.